# Forward UDP traffic to external address with Azure

Tags: azure, udp, portforwarding

we need to accept UDP traffic to a public ip address (which we have and can transfer to Azure) and then have Azure forward that traffic to a specific external ipaddress. It is a simple relay.

We've had a look at using Azure Firewall for this but it doesn't seem to allow us to do it.

If we need to we can try to write a c# app to take the traffic and forward it out but we were hoping to do this without code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a few ways to approach this. Azure firewall may actually do what you want, but of course at a healthy cost.  What is driving the need for this particular configuration?

Comment: So always the cheapest way :) I can perofrm a cost calculation myself once I know the best way to achieve this. We own the ip address that all traffic is sent to and we need to be able to send it on to various other external ips and process it ourselves if we want.  The data comes from multiple different apps out in the field sa UDP packets. We were not involved in the original design. We are paid by these external providers for this and other services.

Comment: It looks like a networl security group will do the trick. We are trying that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the traffic is not very high-volume, you could use Azure Functions or Azure Logic Apps to receive UDP traffic and forward it.

If the traffic is heavy and the final destination is outside Azure you'll have to go with VM as proxy/relay or NVAs you can get from Azure Marketplace. For extra resiliency stick an Azure Load Balancer in front of your VM/NVA.

Comment: As it needs to listen on a UDP port I can't use an Azure Function etc. I have written my own app and installed it on a VM as this seems to be the best way as you have said.

Comment: Actually the bes way ended up creating a Linux VM and using NGINX to do the routing.